# Getting thousands of registration spam

Tags: user-registration, spam, captcha

We have tried the range of Captcha options, and now have Facebook Connect with Akismet installed as a constant, but still can't stop thousands of spam registrations from attacking our WordPress site. There must be a solution. Can anyone help?

Comment: You should read [into this article](http://pippinsplugins.com/i-wrote-some-really-dangerous-code/).

Answer (score 0):

I use the [SI CAPTCHA Anti-Spam](http://www.642weather.com/weather/scripts-wordpress-captcha.php) Plugin in combination with protecting the Site with Cloudflare. Got rid of 99,9% of the Registrationspam, from over a thousand a day to 1-2 a day.